# How do I make Quartz Cron Expression to run at once for a specific year?

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

I'm using **Quartz 2.1.x Distribution** to run a program in Periodic manner. Means in hourly, daily, weekly, yearly basis. I'm able to schedule the program correctly. 
The problem is in Aperiodic scheduling: With the help of Aperiodic Scheduling I want to achieve something like this --> **"0 59 12 26 10 ? 2013"** 
which means it will run on 26th October of 2013 at 12:59 PM. Which should run only once. When I try to execute the above expression with Quartz gives me error. Please suggest me how to perform Aperiodic Scheduling using Quartz or any other API.
Thanks,
Sanchit

Comment: What error does quartz give you?

Comment: The expression is valid, please paste the error you get

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, Actually my program wasn't working at that time (don't know why? ) :P.. But now it is working fine.
Thanks for your comments and suggestions.
Cheers.